# Python/Kivy Multiple screens not working, Code does not recognise the screen manager?

Tags: python, kivy, multiscreen

I am trying to make an app that starts in the main menu, you press the play button and it sends you to the game on a different screen.

Problem is i keep getting an error on the:
"kv= Builder.load_file("my.kv")" saying that "WindowManager" is an unknown class.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

kv= Builder.load_file("my.kv")



class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MenuWindow(Screen):
    pass



class Game(Screen):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv




if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

AND HERE IS THE KV FILE:

```
WindowManager:
    MenuWindow:
    Game:

<MenuWindow>:
    name: "Menu"
    FloatLayout:    
        Button:
            text:"Play"
            on_release:
                app.root.current= "Game"



<Game>:
    name: "Game"
```

Comment: Solved it: 
I had to move the "kv= Builder.load_file("my.kv")"
right below all the class definitions so that the code can run trough them first and then move on to the KV file

Comment: A little suggestion: You can rename your App class's name same with your .kv file name, if both file in same directory. You don't need to connect'em with Builder with this method.